# Surface area of a Hypersphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, intuition

Hypersphere in 4 dimensions, I am having problem with finding the surface area of it. please help.

I know that surface area will have 3 dimensions in 4 dimensional space, I am having trouble to evaluate it

Circumference of circle= $2\pi r$

Surface area of sphere = $4\pi r^2$

Now, Surface area (or whatever, it will be having dimensions of a volume) of hypersphere = ??

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html //
http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14789360/Le-probleme-de-lhyperchevre-

Comment: I didnt understand the concept of line element, thats why i asked here... thnx anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388303/volume-of-a-hypersphere) (see portion below equation (4)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) gives the *volume* of the 4-dimensional hypersphere, with radius $r$, to be
$$V = \frac{\pi^2}{2}r^4$$

The *surface area* can be found by differentiating with respect to $r$:

$$A = \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}r} = 2\pi^2r^3$$

The article also gives a proof of how to calculate the volume, and hence surface area.

Answer (score 1):

Another little known way to get this answer is to double integrate $\sqrt{1 + \nabla f \cdot \nabla f}$, where $f = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}$.

For hyper "areas" of geometric objects in $n$ dimensions, just integrate the above formula $n-1$ times, where $f = f (x_1, x_2, ...,x_{n-1})$.