# Calculate the volume of n-dimensional Sphere $D_n={x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know there are some ready formulas but our topic is triple integrals and I would like to know how to calculate this using it.

If you know the known formulas, I would like to see them either.

Thanks

Comment: [Volume of an n-ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball)

Comment: [A local answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/388332)

Comment: If you require more information, please refine your question to include some context.